# Copy image file from source to destination in PHP

Tags: php

How can we copy image file from source(another server) to destination(our server) without using copy() of php.

Is there any other way possible for it?

Thanks..

Comment: That depends on what kind of relationship the two servers have and how one can access files on the other.

Comment: What is the problem with copy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$url="http://foo.com/foo.jpg";
$name="foo.jpg";
$img= file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($name,$img);
?>
```